# Disable backspace with DOM Level 3 Listeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener, dom3

I am making a page in which a user must be able to type. The default function of backspace is to go back a page, however I need to prevent this and assign my own function to it.

The problem is actually preventing backspace. I can capture it however I can not prevent it.
I am using Level 3 event listeners. `event.preventDefault()` did not work for me and neither did return false.

I have tried this also:

```
function onunload(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) return false;
    return true;
}
```

and

```
<body onunload="return false;">
```

However the first basically does

```
return confirm("false");
```

and the second does nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preventing backspace key altogether might not be a good idea, assume you make a typo and want to fix it in a text box! So you need to disable backspace **only** if someone is not typing in a text input!

This might work in all major browsers:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {                                           // Disable Backspace
        var el = document.activeElement;
        if (!((el.nodeName == "INPUT" && (el.type == "text" || el.type == "password")) || el.nodeName == "TEXTAREA")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

DOM3 event model spec comes with *backward compatibility* so I don't think this might be an issue, however this is the DOM3 modified version of the above code:

```
function KeyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {                                           // Disable Backspace
        var el = document.activeElement;
        if (!((el.nodeName == "INPUT" && (el.type == "text" || el.type == "password")) || el.nodeName == "TEXTAREA")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
};

if (document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent("onkeydown", KeyDownHandler);
else document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyDownHandler);
```

A DOM3 event registration like the one above might be a great pain, [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/) has a good implementation on this, you could however use a standard cross browser library like JQuery which works fine in all major browsers!

Comment: I do not want to disable it - I want to stop it from sending the page back, however fo my use completely disabling it will not be an issue as I have no such generic text input fields.
Also, I have asked for DOM level 3 listeners (ie. addEvent/attach listeners), is that not an option?

Comment: DOM3 comes the *backward compatibility* with DOM2 event model, so the snippet above should work perfectly in any browser compatible with DOM2/3 event model, however I did update the post for solely DOM3 model

Comment: @Shane: if this is the answer to your question, mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, one may prevent default browser shortcut actions by returning false in `keypress` in Firefox only (and last version I tested, was 3.x).

`beforeunload` and `unload` are specific events and string should be returned in their handlers. For security reasons, browser may only display a confirmation dialog with message provided (that string). Moreover, Firefox since version 4 even ignores that string and always displays standard message.

There's no way to silently prevent user from leaving page.

BTW backspace don't work as history.back() in Ubuntu.

Comment: kirilloid, I need it to be cross-browser compatible so I can not use this option. Thank you for your response.

Comment: In Firefox you can prevent default browser behaviour in either `keydown` or `keypress`. It's all here: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `keydown` handler on the `document` level:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
 if (e.keyCode===8) {
   return false;
 }
};
```